# Update Django MPTT Tree from JSON

Tags: jquery, django, tree, mptt

I need to update Django MPTT tree from JSON data. I configure django-mptt with Nestable (http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/) jQuery plugin for edit tree in front-end.

jQuery Nestable provides this data after updating tree:

```
[{
    "id": 1
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "children": [{
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "id": 4
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "children": [{
            "id": 6
        }, {
            "id": 7
        }, {
            "id": 8
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 9
    }, {
        "id": 10
    }]
}, {
    "id": 11
}, {
    "id": 12
}]
```

How i can update my mptt tree from this data?

Thanks!